# Ildasm for .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I've been trying to use Unmanaged Export for project in .NET 4.5, but when compiling it says that:
`Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper could not find ildasm.exe` . And it is mostly true, as there is no folder bin with ildasm.exe at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1`.
Although it is present in this location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin`, I've tried copying `bin` folder, but it doesn't work.
Do you know how can I achieve UnamanagedExport to work with .NET 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just put this here if someone find this question.
To reinstall .NET 4.5 SDK in Visual Studio 2019 (in my case), you have to download and install Microsoft Build Tools 2015.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159

HTH,
Edin

Comment: Does this really answer the question, or is this just "some useful hint"?

Comment: In my case it did indeed help to install Microsoft Build Tools 2015.